# Problems with OpenCV install on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspian 10. I installed OpenCV using [this](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-opencv/) tutorial. The steps seemed to all complete successfully, but I've had some problems importing the python module. When I use Python 3.7.3, I get the following output:

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Which is clearly not working. Using Python 2.7.16 however, it runs fine:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.6.0-dev'
```

Any idea why this may be? It seems like the OpenCV Python module isn't installed globally for Python 3. Ideally, I'd like to be able to use it in a Python 3 virtual environment.

I do have a temporary workaround. If I `cd` into the build directory containing the module, I can get it to work:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd opencv/build/python_loader/
pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv/build/python_loader $ ls
cv2  setup.py
pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv/build/python_loader $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.6.0-dev'
```

Obviously, this isn't ideal.

Comment: you built OpenCV... but not for python3 but for python2. that's the python it got installed in. -- you don't have to build it. just `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python` to get all the modules.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to answer my own question. Running:

`pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv/build $ pip3 install -e python_loader`

Installs the package from the folder containing the module. It's not the most elegant solution, and I'd still be interested to see if anyone knows why the original method didn't work.

Hope this can be of some help to someone.

Comment: so did you uninstall the version of '4.6.0-dev' ?